# Tidy Pandas dataframe: operations on existing rows and appending results

Tags: pandas

I have a tidy dataframe `tidy`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
    import uuid
    import random

    tidy = pd.DataFrame(columns=['measure_type', 'sensor', 'value'])
    for measurement, sensor in zip(5*['type_a'] + 5*['type_b'], 
                                   2*[uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(5)]
                                   ):
        tidy = tidy.append(pd.Series({'measure_type':measurement, 
                                      'sensor':sensor,
                                      'value':random.random()
                                      }
                                     ), ignore_index=True)
>>> tidy
        measure_type    sensor                                  value
    0   type_a          f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325    0.323960
    1   type_a          f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b    0.727934
    2   type_a          d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9    0.357074
    3   type_a          4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd    0.312051
    4   type_a          e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891    0.750661
    5   type_b          f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325    0.424161
    6   type_b          f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b    0.608558
    7   type_b          d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9    0.759485
    8   type_b          4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd    0.095980
    9   type_b          e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891    0.382245
```

I want to append to this tidy dataframe 5 more rows that are, for each sensor, the difference between reading type_a and reading type_b. Measurement type for these new rows is type_c

The way I have found to do this simply is too long to be right. Here is what works:

```
>>> df_a = tidy[tidy['measure_type']=='type_a'] # New df with readings for a only
>>> df_a.set_index(keys='sensor', inplace=True) # Make sensor ID the key
>>> df_a.drop('measure_type', axis=1, inplace=True) #Keep only the reading value
>>> df_a

sensor                                  value    
f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325    0.323960
f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b    0.727934
d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9    0.357074
4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd    0.312051
e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891    0.750661
```

And doing the same for type_b...

```
[...]
>>> df_b
sensor                                  value    
f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325    0.424161
f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b    0.608558
d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9    0.759485
4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd    0.095980
e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891    0.382245
```

Now I can subtract the two:

```
>>> df_c = df_a - df_b
```

I need to add a column with the measurement type:

```
>>> df_c['measure_type'] = 'type_c'
```

Only then can I append, and I have to reset the index:

```
>>> tidy = tidy.append(c)
>>> tidy.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> tidy
    measure_type   sensor                               value
0   type_a         f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325 0.323960
1   type_a         f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b 0.727934
2   type_a         d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9 0.357074
3   type_a         4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd 0.312051
4   type_a         e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891 0.750661
5   type_b         f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325 0.424161
6   type_b         f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b 0.608558
7   type_b         d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9 0.759485
8   type_b         4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd 0.095980
9   type_b         e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891 0.382245
10  type_c         f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325 -0.100200
11  type_c         f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b 0.119377
12  type_c         d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9 -0.402411
13  type_c         4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd 0.216071
14  type_c         e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891 0.368416
```

This simply cannot be the simplest way to do this.

**EDIT**

The method should also work with `tidy2` and `tidy3` where:

```
tidy2 = tidy.drop(1)
```

and

```
tidy3 = tidy
tidy3.loc[0, 'sensor']='some other uuid'
```

i.e. in cases where the keys of or numbers of observations in each sensor is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit to meet tidy2 and tidy3 conditions with Nan returns:

```
pd.concat([tidy,
           tidy.groupby(['sensor'])
               .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.measure_type == 'type_a','value'].max()-x.loc[x.measure_type == 'type_b','value'].min())
               .reset_index().assign(measure_type='type_c')
               .rename(columns={0:'value'})]).replace(0,pd.np.nan)
```

Let's try:

```
pd.concat([tidy,
           tidy.groupby(['sensor'])
               .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0,2]-x.iloc[1,2])
               .reset_index().assign(measure_type='type_c')
               .rename(columns={0:'value'})])
```

Output:

```
  measure_type                                sensor     value
0       type_a  3bbbe393-74bc-4c77-b95c-fbaaac64ed3f  0.638573
1       type_a  b9b72088-078a-4dd6-91b5-f9e6643a9d43  0.468320
2       type_a  4f90f177-0ed8-4ff5-b635-f317925aebcc  0.945822
3       type_a  307db09c-6b46-4518-b822-7771ab97fbbe  0.886271
4       type_a  061bf0f3-9870-4426-9327-a9e7d9208923  0.757897
5       type_b  3bbbe393-74bc-4c77-b95c-fbaaac64ed3f  0.922330
6       type_b  b9b72088-078a-4dd6-91b5-f9e6643a9d43  0.711345
7       type_b  4f90f177-0ed8-4ff5-b635-f317925aebcc  0.501771
8       type_b  307db09c-6b46-4518-b822-7771ab97fbbe  0.381833
9       type_b  061bf0f3-9870-4426-9327-a9e7d9208923  0.399346
0       type_c  061bf0f3-9870-4426-9327-a9e7d9208923  0.358551
1       type_c  307db09c-6b46-4518-b822-7771ab97fbbe  0.504438
2       type_c  3bbbe393-74bc-4c77-b95c-fbaaac64ed3f -0.283757
3       type_c  4f90f177-0ed8-4ff5-b635-f317925aebcc  0.444052
4       type_c  b9b72088-078a-4dd6-91b5-f9e6643a9d43 -0.243025
```

Comment: Over this data, yours is quicker

Comment: No... but I'm trying to simplify it.

Comment: Ok, I learned much here, but I understand that this only works because my groupby's automatically align (same lenght, sorted, etc.). If I delete a row, then this method fails (IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds). I will update my question to state that the answer should ensure alignement based on all other columns (in this case, that is only "sensor").

Comment: @Mpa.. Okay have a look now at this tweak to handle tidy2 and tidy3

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm wondering why `.min()` and `.max()` rather than nothing (`iloc` should return the value) or `.values`

Comment: Just incase of multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

```
tidy.set_index(['sensor', 'measure_type']).value.unstack() \
    .eval('type_c = type_a - type_b', inplace=False).stack() \
    .sort_index(level='measure_type').swaplevel(0, 1).reset_index(name='value')

   measure_type                                sensor     value
0        type_a  4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd  0.312051
1        type_a  d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9  0.357074
2        type_a  e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891  0.750661
3        type_a  f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b  0.727934
4        type_a  f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325  0.323960
5        type_b  4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd  0.095980
6        type_b  d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9  0.759485
7        type_b  e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891  0.382245
8        type_b  f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b  0.608558
9        type_b  f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325  0.424161
10       type_c  4a384d86-6288-49f3-be5d-8d54a811b9bd  0.216071
11       type_c  d59d29ec-32cb-4853-b822-8ac9abec07b9 -0.402411
12       type_c  e59f5497-eb25-4084-816a-297d67768891  0.368416
13       type_c  f3724608-3c28-49c7-a237-09b02a75694b  0.119376
14       type_c  f9726059-1352-49fb-9cc7-cffdf84db325 -0.100201
```

Comment: This works with tidy, tidy2 and tidy3! I still need to unpack it fully, but quick question: right now, for tidy2 and tidy3, when the .eval could not evaluate, no row was added. Is there a tweak to allow a NaN to be returned instead?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head... I'll figure it out.